# How to get data of a website when a link is pasted of typed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys any idea on how to make something like this? where you paste or type a link and it display a little content of that website just like what facebook did using JavaScript or react js

[image]

Comment: https://andrejgajdos.com/how-to-create-a-link-preview/

Comment: you can't achieve only from ReactJS / frontend, it would need to parse url in your backend and reveal to frontend.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an iframe to show another website on your website

Comment: it's not a good idea, OP is looking to parse url meta info like FB, although most of sites prevented by `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header